# Mixed attr_accessible and strong_parameters, how to skip attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, activerecord

First of all, I am **fully aware** of the bad practice with mixing the two.

I have a model that has `attr_accessible` set up. I'd like to start transitioning our application to `strong_parameters`. The problem is that I need to do this piecemeal as we refactor individual parts of the application. Is there a ActiveRecord method I can use to update the attributes that bypasses `attr_accessible` for right now? Or can I define a `attr_accessible=false` type of thing that bypasses it?

Code example:

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  def update
    @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
    @user.save!
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
                                  :first_name, :last_name, :email, :other_attribute_not_in_accessible
                                )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

In the controller, do this:

```
@user.update_attributes(user_params,:without_protection=>true)
```

And then it'll work.